# How do I expose all buttons when a certain number(mine) is clicked in java minesweeper?

Tags: java, button, non-static, minesweeper

I am trying to build a minesweeper program, and I currently have clickable buttons with the correct number of mines displayed. I was wondering how to reveal all buttons when a mine is clicked. I am trying to do this without making all my fields static, as I hope to change the game up once I'm done.

```
public class Minesweeper {  
    /*
    The following code initializes the 2d array's fields for
    positions, with its rows, columns, and # of mines.
    */
    ArrayList<Integer> minenums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int mineNum;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int[][] grid; 
    static boolean gameOn = true;
    static Minesweeper sweep;
    Button[][] buttons;

     public void exposeAll() {
         if(gameOn = false){
             for(int i =0; i < rows; i++){
                 for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                     //     buttons[i][j].expose();
                 }
             }
        }    
    }
}

public class MouseWhisperer implements MouseListener {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
       int value;
       Button click; 
       click = (Button)me.getSource();
       click.expose();
       value = ((Button)click).getvalue();
       if (value == -1) {
           for(int i = 0; i < Minesweeper.sweep.grid.length; i++){
               for(int j = 0; j < Minesweeper.sweep.grid[0].length; j++){
                   Minesweeper.sweep.buttons[i][j].expose();
               }
           }
       }
    }
)
```

There aren't any error messages, the method does not work when a mine (value = -1) is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by "reveal"? What is "expose" actually doing? Could you post the whole code?

Comment: Please make your code **compilable** (use [Edit]).

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Why are you not using `exposeAll()` in `MouseWhisperer`? Why is `Minesweeper` a singleton class? Why is your question tagged 'non-static' when Minesweeper is a singleton class?

Comment: You need to include more of your code. How are you setting the value of Minesweeper.sweep? Are you initializing grid? As trvlr pointed out, you should be calling Minesweeper.sweep.exposeAll() from your MouseListener. Have you tried putting a break point inside you MouseListener to watch what the control flow does? Also, you should be able to access the parent of the button to get to the other buttons if you don't want to use a static reference to your main class (which is a singleton pattern).

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> minenums = new ArrayList<Integer>();` mine indexes require an X and Y value. Are you sure you want to do this?